# How can i use requier and import statments in node js , at the same file

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, typeerror, package.json

my problem when i was working on my node js file , is that im importing readline statments , and using ( `'type': 'module'` )  at the same time , wanting to use both ways while no errors
how can i use requier on ( readline ) command ?
the type of error im facing is :

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

i tried to use module on ( packag.json) but then the requier statment will face type error
i couldnt ( transfare) (`import readline, { clearScreenDown } from "readline";` ) as an a requier statement like this (`const db = require('./dbConnection');`)

Answer (score 0):

You can't, they're mutually-exclusive. `import` is [ESM](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) (JavaScript's native, specified module system), and `require` is [CommonJS](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) (Node.js's older module system).

Instead, you have to use ESM or CommonJS consistently.

If you need to do a dynamic (runtime-determined) import in ESM, you can use the [`import()` pseudo-function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#dynamic_imports), which is a bit like CommonJS `require` except that rather than making the calling code wait, it returns a promise.

Answer (score 0):

Answer depends on the choice of method you want to use.

1. Use `import ABC from 'ABC'` (node core module or packages downloaded via npm)
2. User `const abc = require('./ABC')` for your custom modules. below are examples.

**ABC.js**

```js
const ABC = ()=> {
 return "ABC is called";
}
module.exports=ABC;
```

now in file you want to call it.
**index.js**

```js
const abc = require('./ABC');
```